# Missing MSVCP100.dll even with Runtime Library set to /MT

Tags: c++, visual-studio

I created a program using Visual Studio 2010 and it runs fine on my computer, but on another machine it gives this error:

[image]

Now, I've done my research and I came up with at least 20 identical answers that all say the same thing: Configure your Runtime Library to /MT (or /MTd for debug) and rebuild. Great, only problem is that I already did just that and it still doesn't work...

Now, the alternative would be to force the users to install the Microsoft VS 2010 C++ Redistributable Package, but I'd very much like to avoid that. So any explanation as to why my solution is not working? Something weird worth mentioning is that my executable size doesn't seem to change even when I rebuild it with /MT, which makes no sense. Also, I'm not using any CLR support.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: What if you build your application statically? Unless you build statically you are going to be required to have the required DLLs in place. Your subject mentions one DLL but your screenshot shows MSVCR110.dll which is the C runtime code.

Comment: ***Now, the alternative would be to force the users to install the Microsoft VS 2013 C++ Redistributable*** You mean Visual Studio 2010 Redistributable. The missing file is from Visual Studio 2010. If you are using Visual Studio 2013 make sure you are not using dlls compiled by a different version of Visual Studio. Also since you want to statically link you should not be using 3rd party dlls at all.

Comment: Ah my bad, I took the image on the internet and didn't even realize it was the wrong dll... Definitely meant to show MSVCP100.dll. Although you say build statically, but is it not what I'm doing with runtime Library set to /MT? All my dlls are compiled by Visual Studio 2010 and yea, I mean't Visual Studio 2010 Redistributable.

Comment: Make sure all the dlls use a static runtime. If these are 3rd party dlls you will most likely have to build them yourself since it is highly unlikely that 3rd party dlls will be built with a static runtime.

Comment: @SoftEngi: No, /MT does not mean "static build" because that would also link all libraries statically that are available as a static version. /MT just covers the runtime. And it may very well be, that some library you use depends on that DLL. In that case you can either rebuild that library, if you have the sources, or just bite the bullet of shipping that DLL.

Comment: I'm only using one DLL that I made myself, and it's also set to /MT

Comment: Did you try a clean build of the dll + application.

Comment: Yup, tried that already!

Comment: I assume you are not using MFC.

Comment: You assume correctly, do I have to?

Comment: I'm assuming you aren't using /MT and /MD together.

Comment: My project builds one exe and one DLL, both using /MT, and not using any other DLL.

Comment: ***do I have to?*** No. That was the only other way I could think of the dependency on the dynamic runtime.

Comment: If it were me I'd use something like http://www.dependencywalker.com/ to find what component requires a particular dll.